# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 Error

Tags: java

I have got this error several times and I can't find any solution, I have read in other questions here that it is due to trying to read an array index that doesn't exist.
I'm not able to find the problem and it only happens when I send the single quoted string (that is supoused to be a complete JSON but I'm only sending that part for testing, it will throw the same error if a send the complete single quoted JSON) but if I send a simple string such as my name it won't give any problems and print it like it should

```
public class Parser {

    public String x;    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printLn("Hola!");
        String zxc;
        zxc = ("'variable':[1,'Double']}");
        Parse(zxc);
    }
    public static void Parse(String chain){

        int len1 = chain.lastIndexOf("'variable':[");
        int asd = len1+1;
        String[] chainArr = new String[]{chain};
        printLn(chainArr[asd]);


    }

    public static void printLn(String cadena){
        System.out.println(cadena);
    }
    public static void printLn(String[] cadena){
        System.out.println(cadena);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Error Log says:

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   1         at comp.juan.Parser.Parse(Parser.java:18)       at
>   comp.juan.Parser.main(Parser.java:11)"

Please :X

Comment: Share your exact error log..!!

Comment: Sorry, totally forgot since I put it on the title, Ill do it right now

Comment: What you are trying to achieve here puzzle me.. But  when you do `chainArr[asd]`, with `asd` bigger than the size of `chainArr` you get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`. ([ideone](https://ideone.com/i92RmX) of posted code)

Comment: You create an array of length 1, then you index len1+1 into it.   What exactly are you trying to do there?   That makes no sense.   If this is not a school assignment where the goal is to write a JSON parser, please don't try to write a JSON parser.   Just use one that's already out there... =)

Comment: You **will** get `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` obviously, what else did you expect? `lastIndexOf` `'variable':[` in your string is `0` so `asd` will be `1`. You create an array of length `1` and then try to access index `1` in it.

Comment: chainArr is always an array with length 1, i don't think String[] chainArr = new String[]{chain};is what you really intend

Comment: you create an array of Strings, with the size of 1 (it contains chain), and then try to get chainArr[something bigger than 1]. I guess what you want is, chain.substring(asd);

Comment: see my answer below @JuanUrdaneta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @janki, Now If your purpose to parse the json string, you can modify your code as below also:

```
public static void Parse(String chain){

    String result[] = chain.split(":");
    printLn(result[0]);
    printLn(result[1]);
}
```

Hope It may help you write short code for the same purpose.

Answer (score 4):

It is because you have only one element in your String `Array` i.e. at `0th` index but you are trying to print other then 0th index. I think `1st` or greater '0' in sort.

Your code :

```
String[] chainArr = new String[]{chain};
printLn(chainArr[asd]);
```

will convert the whole string `'variable':[1,'Double']}` in String Array. So it will become.

```
chainArr[0] = "'variable':[1,'Double']}";
```

Comment: Oh, thanks alot! it wasn't the actual problem but is good to know something new!, I come from javascript and getting used to java is a little rough but it also is exiting.

Comment: Happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Already solve it thanks to Turo in the comments, What I really intended was to get the character at a specific position in the String. I was using `indexOf()` when I what I wanted to use was `charAt()`.

`indexOf` would return the position of the character in the string, `charAt` would return the character, the character was what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I traced your code why you have ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, Please see the following..

```
  int asd = len1+1; //asd =1 
  String[] chainArr = new String[]{chain}; 
  //String[0]='variable':[1,'Double']} 
  System.out.println(chainArr[asd]); //chainArr Array have only zero index.
```

---